# button that creates a copy of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button next to a text box and when I click the button i want it to create another button next to another text box. This code is doing just that but the new button doesn't work.

```
<div id="algorithm">
    <input type="button" id="add_child" value="+" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox0" />
</div>

$('#add_child').click(function() {
    $('<input type="button" id="add_child" value="+" />').appendTo('#algorithm');
    $('<input type="text" id="textbox0" />').appendTo('#algorithm');
});
```

Comment: because you're using same `id` on both

Comment: Also, the copied button won't inherit a function defined as `$("...").click(...)`, as that is a one time binding. You will need to rebind the function, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest trying this approach:

```
$('#algorithm').on('click','input',function(){
    $(this).clone(true,true).insertAfter($(this));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WZTP9/).

Revised the above code to update the `id` attribute so that there are no duplicates:

```
$('#algorithm').on('click','input',function(){
    $(this).clone(true,true).attr('id','add_child' + $('input[type="button"]').length).insertAfter($(this));
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WZTP9/2/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Really my ultimate goal is to create a text box that has little plus signs to the left and right of it that make a 'sibling' text box, and a plus sign below it to make a 'child' text box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of issues with you code.

first of all; you binding is not live so any new elements you add will not get the same functionality.

Secondly you're creating multiple elements with the same id... a BIG no no!

Thirdly since your'e using an ID selector it will stop looking avter it finds the firs one, but i do have a hunch that it WOULD work if you changed your binding to $().live("click", function(){})

Comment: Yeah Im pretty much brand new to this but how would i make it just inherit the functionality from a class. aka, i dont really know how to make a class that is not a css class?